# Wired mouse cursor moving extremely slow

Tags: windows-7, performance, mouse, cursor, wired

I have a wired HP mouse that has been working fine for many months with my laptop. Suddenly the cursor started moving extremely slow. I have read other online articles on this issue but nothing seems to be helpful.

- This is a wired mouse, so low batteries are out of the picture
- I have tried increasing the speed of the mouse cursor under Control Panel but it doesn't make a difference - it only increases the speed of the cursor on the laptop's touchpad
- There is virtually no dust or hair trapped in the optical sensor area of the mouse
- If I use a mousepad, the performance of the cursor is better but the issue is not completely solved
- I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling the mouse driver but it doesn't change anything
- I've tried on two laptops and have the same issue

Comment: "I've tried on two laptops and have the same issue" Buy a new mouse.

Comment: Is there a DPI switch on the mouse? https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/support/how-to/mouse/change-mouse-sensitivity

Comment: No DPI switch. Its a simple wired mouse. Thank you.